# why the properties map to yaml return null

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, properties-file

I have a java properties config look like this:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[9].id = dict-auth
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[9].order = 0
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[9].predicates[0] = Path=/dict/user/plugin/login
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[9].uri = http://10.98.176.2:11014
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[10].filters[0] = RewritePath=/dict/auth/access_token/refresh, /post/auth/access_token/refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[10].id = dict-access-token-refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[10].order = 1
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[10].predicates[0] = Path=/dict/auth/access_token/refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[10].uri = http://10.98.176.2:11014
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].filters[0] = RewritePath=/dict/auth/refresh_token/refresh, /post/auth/refresh_token/refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].id = dict-refresh-token-refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].order = 2
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].predicates[0] = Path=/dict/auth/refresh_token/refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].uri = http://10.98.176.2:11014
```

when I am using [online tool](https://www.toyaml.com/index1.html) map to yaml, shows result like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - null
      - null
      - null
      - null
      - null
      - null
      - null
      - null
      - null
      - id: dict-auth
        order: 0
        predicates:
        - Path=/dict/user/plugin/login
        uri: http://10.98.176.2:11014
      - null
      - filters:
        - RewritePath=/dict/auth/access_token/refresh, /post/auth/access_token/refresh
        id: dict-access-token-refresh
        order: 1
        predicates:
        - Path=/dict/auth/access_token/refresh
        uri: http://10.98.176.2:11014
      - filters:
        - RewritePath=/dict/auth/refresh_token/refresh, /post/auth/refresh_token/refresh
        id: dict-refresh-token-refresh
        order: 2
        predicates:
        - Path=/dict/auth/refresh_token/refresh
        uri: http://10.98.176.2:11014
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this problem? BTW, this is the full config of route looks like:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0].name = JwtAuthentication
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id = time-capsule-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].order = 2
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0] = Path=/tik/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri = http://10.111.149.10:11015
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].filters[0].name = JwtAuthentication
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id = fortune-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].order = 2
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0] = Path=/fortune/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri = http://10.96.112.198:11015
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].filters[0].name = JwtAuthentication
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].id = dolphin-music-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates[0] = Path=/music/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].uri = http://10.107.64.246:11014
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].filters[0].name = JwtAuthentication
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].id = dolphin-post-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].predicates[0] = Path=/post/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].uri = http://10.98.176.2:11014
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].filters[0].name = JwtAuthentication
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].id = dolphin-manage-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].order = 2
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].predicates[0] = Path=/manage/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].uri = http://10.106.240.158:11015
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].id = dolphin-login-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].order = 0
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].predicates[0] = Path=/manage/admin/user/login,/fortune/user/login,/fortune/user/sms,/fortune/user/reg/verify,/fortune/user/guest/login,/dict/user/login
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].uri = http://10.98.176.2:11014
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[6].id = dolphin-logout-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[6].order = 0
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[6].predicates[0] = Path=/manage/admin/user/logout
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[6].uri = http://10.98.176.2:11014
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[7].id = dolphin-login-current-admin-user
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[7].order = 0
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[7].predicates[0] = Path=/manage/admin/user/current-user
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[7].uri = http://10.98.176.2:11014
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[8].filters[0].name = JwtAuthentication
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[8].id = dolphin-dict-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[8].order = 3
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[8].predicates[0] = Path=/dict/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[8].uri = http://10.97.100.34:11014
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[9].id = dict-auth
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[9].order = 0
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[9].predicates[0] = Path=/dict/user/plugin/login
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[9].uri = http://10.98.176.2:11014
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[10].filters[0] = RewritePath=/dict/auth/access_token/refresh, /post/auth/access_token/refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[10].id = dict-access-token-refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[10].order = 1
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[10].predicates[0] = Path=/dict/auth/access_token/refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[10].uri = http://10.98.176.2:11014
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].filters[0] = RewritePath=/dict/auth/refresh_token/refresh, /post/auth/refresh_token/refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].id = dict-refresh-token-refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].order = 2
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].predicates[0] = Path=/dict/auth/refresh_token/refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].uri = http://10.98.176.2:11014
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `spring.cloud.gateway.routes` is a list of route object , and the number inside the bracket is the index position (0-based) of each route. Now you do not specify anything for `spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0]` up to `spring.cloud.gateway.routes[8]` , so the first 9 items in the `yml` is null.

To fix it, you have to rename the index to :

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id = dict-auth
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].order = 0
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0] = Path=/dict/user/plugin/login
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri = http://10.98.176.2:11014
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].filters[0] = RewritePath=/dict/auth/access_token/refresh, /post/auth/access_token/refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id = dict-access-token-refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].order = 1
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0] = Path=/dict/auth/access_token/refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri = http://10.98.176.2:11014
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].filters[0] = RewritePath=/dict/auth/refresh_token/refresh, /post/auth/refresh_token/refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].id = dict-refresh-token-refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].order = 2
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates[0] = Path=/dict/auth/refresh_token/refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].uri = http://10.98.176.2:11014
```

Comment: I have already have the 1-9 config, that I am not pasted to the question. @Ken Chan